# How to compile c & c++ programs?

Tags: c++, c

I read somewhere that I need to install 'build essential packager' & so I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But the file still wont compile or run...

```
gcc -Wall -W -Werror factorial.cpp -o factorial.
```

gives me:

```
gcc -Wall -W -Werror factorial.cpp -o factorial.
factorial.cpp:3:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

This is my piece of code:
//WAP to demonstrate static member for calculating factorial

```
    #include<iostream.h>    
    #include<conio.h>
class fact
{
int i;
    static int count;
    public : 
    void calculate()
    {
        long int fact1=1;
        count++;
        for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
        {
            fact1=fact1*i;
        }
        cout<<"\nFactorial of"<<count<<"="<<fact1<<"\n";
    }
};
int fact :: count;
void main()
{
    int i;
    clrscr();
    fact f;
    for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
    {
        f.calculate();
    }
    getch();
}
```

What shoud I do..???

Comment: This is a programming question (with lots of programming errors) and so should be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). The only platform specific bit is the use of [conio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) which isn't available for Ubuntu (or most other Unix like platforms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with your test source package.

My guess is that you are trying to compile using slightly older C++ standards (`gcc` instead of `g++`) and probably based on a Windows routine (using `conio`).

I've tidied up the test program for you:

```cpp
#include <iostream> /* dont need .h */    
using namespace std; /* use a namespace */
/* #include <conio.h>   this is a windows header - dont need */

class fact
{
int i;
    static int count;
    public : 
    void calculate()
    {
        long int fact1=1;
        count++;
        for (i = 2; i <= count; i++)
        {
            fact1 *= i;
        }
        cout << "\nFactorial of " << count << '=' << fact1 << '\n';
    }
};
int fact :: count;

int main(void) /* you had an invalid main declaration */
{
    int i;
    /* clrscr();  not necessary */
    fact f;
    for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        f.calculate();
    }
    /* getch(); not necessary */

    return 0; /* need to return a standard value */
}
```

then compile using

```
g++ factorial.cpp -o factorial
```

Comment: The calculate loop also needs to start at i=1 or the result will always be 0.

Comment: Good comment - there are many issues with this source - very inefficient etc.  My main aim for the answer was just to get this thing to compile!

Answer (score 0):

Try: `#include <iostream>`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214230/iostream-vs-iostream-h-vs-iostream-h

Answer (score -1):

Try another one just to test because it says `No such file or directory`. Or maybe the source file is corrupted.