# How to compile a C program that uses pthread.h?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner and I'm new to Ubuntu. I just installed it and want to run a C program. I have no idea what platform to use or where to write the code. I need to use the pthread.h header file in the program. Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile c & c++ programs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53358/how-to-compile-c-c-programs)

Answer (score 24):

Use:

```
gcc MyProgram.c -o MyProgram -lpthread
```

and dont forget to include the POSIX  library in your code. It will compile your code.

Comment: by default GCC does not include the pthread library. so you have to include the library using lpthread argument.

Comment: Also note that in gcc-4.8 there is not `-lpthread` argument in `man gcc`. But there is a `-pthread` argument. Both work fine on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc-4.8.

Comment: this is so wrong answer. you need `-pthread` both for compilation and linking options

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to compile a C program with **pthread.h** in LINUX using GCC or G++ you will have to use **–lpthread** option after the compile command.

```
gcc xyz.c -o xyz -lpthread
```

**Here,**

**gcc** is compiler command (compiler name)
**xyz.c** is a source file name.
**-o** is an option to create objcect file.
**xyz** is the name of object (binary) file.
**-lpthread** is an option for pthread.h

for more details here is the link conatining complete article on it. 
***[Compiling C program with pthread.h in Linux.](http://www.includehelp.com/c-programming-questions/compiling-program-with-pthread-library-linux.aspx)***

Answer (score -1):

First thing you'll need in Ubuntu to compile C/C++ programs is installing GCC (Gnu Compiler Collection) which is part of `build-essential` package , do that by running:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then you can test if you have it installed by running `gcc`. If you you see error like `Fatal error: file not provided` (not sure exact error message, but should be something similar), that means you have compiler ready.

And for editing your Code, you can use already available **Gedit**, just search for it in Dash.

Now following is the syntax to compile your C source file, run following where your file is:

```
gcc MyProgram.c -o MyProgram
```

Where, switch `-o` is optional, but provided to mention name of Binary file which should be created out of your source.

Then simply run `./MyProgram` to run your binary.

Note that `pthread.h` as you mentioned (POSIX Thread) should be available by default with GCC, so simply including it in your C file will do that job, in case it's not available, a simple Google search should help. ;)

**Update**

Too long, didn't read? check [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C-Program-Using-the-GNU-Compiler-%28GCC%29). :D

Answer (score -1):

If it gives error than you can try out same command by interchanging the parameters as like

```
gcc -lpthread -o output_file program_pthread.c
```

after that `./output_file` provides output for program and here `program_pthread.c` is the pthread program you have implemented.

Answer (score -1):

For C++ program:

```
g++ -std=c++11 Myprogram.cpp -o MyProgramTest -lpthread
```